# How to subset observations based on factor level

Tags: r, subset, cut

I have a data frame and need to group the observations based on one variable(vector)'s value into equal number of groups. Below is to illustrate, I used to cut function to create factor based on vector A' value. It create three levels, and each value of the vector A fall into one of the level/group. Now how do I extract/refer to the vector A value based on the cut level of X. For instance, if I want to select observations of A fall into level 1:[1.2.33], how to do that?

```
> A<-1:5  
> X<-cut(A,breaks=quantile(A,probs=c(0:3)/3),labels=1:3,include.lowest=TRUE)  
> A  
[1] 1 2 3 4 5  
> X  
[1] [1,2.33]    [1,2.33]    (2.33,3.67] (3.67,5]    (3.67,5]   
Levels: [1,2.33] (2.33,3.67] (3.67,5]
```

Comment: Your code has at least 2 inconsistencies. 1. You define `A` and then use `a`. 2. You have a typo on `lables` which results in this range-like levels.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a better example than what you provided:

```
> v <-1:10
> X <- cut(v, breaks=quantile(v,probs=c(0:3)/3), labels=letters[1:3], include.lowest=TRUE)
> X
 [1] a a a a b b b c c c
Levels: a b c
```

Two select values from `v` which correspond to level `"a"`, just run:

```
> v[X=="a"]
[1] 1 2 3 4
```

Comment: What if I want to create a lot of groups such as percentile. And I want to group observation based on the percentile group number. Instead of subset by specify range of each group. Is there a way to automatically assign percentile group number/index to each observations? (Similar to Proc Rank in SAS)

Comment: Instead of label as a,b,c, how can I label them as 1,2,3 to rank order the group?

Comment: You can just use `labels=1:3`, I changed to letters to highlight that they were labels, since the example data was also integers.